# Adding hyperlinks fails to allow cut and paste

Tags: bug, status-completed

Trying to insert a hyperlink now fails as I cannot paste into the pop up box.

This worked in beta and still does on other stack exchange sites.

Comment: how odd, indeed I can confirm this..

Comment: Yeah, it works if you delete the `http://` before pasting

Comment: Thanks for that Griffo - I've just been clicking ok with the http:// url, and then pasting my own link after that. Kind of a pain, but should be an easy fix

Comment: i didn't even realize this was a bug... happened to me and i thought it was just a fluke

Comment: could mark the answer as accepted here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: This must be the absolutely weirdest browser bug I've ever seen (it only happens in Chrome). This was caused by a CSS rule that has nothing to do with anything even *remotely* related to that input box.

Comment: For those interested, this is the bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60057

Comment: I found it in Omniweb and Safari not Chrome